# Spring Security error when annotating with @Preauthorize multiple controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, annotations

I am able to annotate with @Preauthorize only one controller's methods. When i try to annotate a second controller's methods, i get this exception:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'allController' defined in file [/Users/alberto/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.3.RELEASE/base-instance/wtpwebapps/sp/WEB-INF/classes/com/ap/sp/AllController.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but found []
```

I'm using only java config.
Here is my security configuration (i want to accept all requests and perform permission check at method level using @Preauthorize)

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

     @Autowired
     public void registerGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, enabled FROM auth_users WHERE username = ?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, authority FROM auth_authorities WHERE username = ?");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll();
    }

}
```

This is the only controller i can annotate methods (if i annotate only this controller everything works correctly):

```
@Controller
public class SecurityController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityController.class);


    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public SecResponse handleCustomException(AccessDeniedException ex) {

        logger.error("exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        SecResponse resp = new SecResponse();
        resp.status = "ERROR";
        return resp;

    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sec/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public SecResponse secAdmin() {

        SecResponse resp = new SecResponse();
        resp.role = Roles.ADMIN;

        return resp;
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sec/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public SecResponse secUser() {

        SecResponse resp = new SecResponse();
        resp.role = Roles.USER;

        return resp;
    }       

}
```

When i create a new controller and annotate its methods, i get the exception shown at the beginning

```
@Controller
public class AllController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AllController.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public SecResponse handleCustomException(AccessDeniedException ex) {

        logger.error("exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        SecResponse resp = new SecResponse();
        resp.status = "ERROR";
        return resp;

    }



    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")   
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/all/one", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String one() {

        return "one";
    }


}
```

I just want to be able to annotate methods on different controllers. Can you tell me how to do it and why i get that exception if i annotate another controller's method?

Comment: What are you using as root configuration to setup spring?

Answer (score 1):

There are some required steps, that you have to do before using `@PreAuthorize` annotation with your Java Config:

1. In your main security config you have to specify annotation for enabling global method security:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity        
   @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
   ```
2. Mark a method you want to protect using `@PreAuthorize` annotation (by the way, @Override should give you a thought about programming in interfaces):

   ```
   @Service (value = "defaultSecuredService")
   public class DefaultSecuredService implements SecuredService {

       @Override
       @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
       public String findSimpleString() {
           return "simple string";
       }

   }
   ```
3. Make sure that your bean is added to Spring context and is instanciated using `INTERFACE`:

   ```
   @Controller
   public class IndexController {

       @Autowired
       private SecuredService defaultSecuredService;

       @RequestMapping (value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public ModelAndView getIndexPage() {
           ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
           modelAndView.setViewName("index");
           modelAndView.addObject("simpleString", defaultSecuredService.findSimpleString());

           return modelAndView;
       }

   }
   ```